# Экспоненциальная форма записи числа

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

Можно ли как-нибудь записывать маленькое либо большое число без экспоненциальной формы, т.е. как есть?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ничего не ясно, у Вас число исходное какое(int, double или string и тд) и что хотите получить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если изначально данные хранятся в строке, то можно так:

```
 Double.valueOf("9.18E+09").longValue()
```

или так:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("9.18E+09");
long val = bd.longValue();
```

Comment: Странно, это совсем не ответ на вопрос.